# react-native-face-detection failed iOS build while uploading on TestFlight

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, app-thinning

I use react-native-face-detection package for my project.
After using above package my iOS application reject on testflight due to below error.

`While processing your iOS app, errors occurred in the app thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. If your app contains bitcode, bitcode processing may have failed. Because of these errors, this build of your app will not be able to be submitted for review or placed on the App Store. For information that may help resolve this issue, see Tech Note 2432.`

react-native-face-detection package using `GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection` in background.

I just need to check in my react-native app is that uploaded image have human face or not on machine not cloud.

react-native-version : 0.63.4